# Fixed element - Not staying fixed due to plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed modal, that works on all pages apart from the ones I am using this plugin on: https://smoove.js.org/

The plugin adds some css to the body tag which seems to stop the modal using "fixed": 
`style="overflow-x: hidden; perspective: 1000px;"`

This is the styling for my overlay modal which is triggered using the top right button on the page. http://www.rubix.london/test/#

[image]

```
display:block;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: rgba(0, 26, 140, 0.6);
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
z-index: 9999999;
transform: none;
```

This stops my fixed modal overlay scrolling with the page and instead fixes it to the top of the page. I cannot for the life of my figure out why? is there any rules I can set to over-ride this?

The site is here: http://www.rubix.london/test/#

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: Did you try to use `!important`

Comment: @FloWy yes, this did not work. Looking at dev tools, it doesn't appear its being over riden.

Comment: I made the body perspective:none!important. Overiding the 1000px... and its fixed it.